# "Fuse" 2 strings together

Tags: java, string, loops

I came across an exercice where I have to add a number of spaces depending on the length of a given string. This is the code I have:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String[] NAMES = {"Spa reine 25cl","Bru plate 50cl","Bru pét 50cl",
                "Pepsi","Spa orange", "Schweppes Tonic","Schweppes Agr","Ice Tea","Ice Tea Pêche",
                "Jus d'orange Looza", "Cécémel", "Red Bull"};
        int[][] stock = {{1,56,200,55},{2,42,200,60},{3,62,200,125},{4,45,200,150},{5,25,200,140},{6,72,200,86},{7,40,200,47},{8,48,200,80},{9,24,150,75},{10,36,200,90},{11,15,100,55},{12,25,80,23}};
        
        for(int i = 0; i<NAMES.length;i++) {
            String space1 = placeNumberToRank(NAMES[i], Integer.toString(stock[i][1]), 35);
            String space2 = placeNumberToRank(NAMES[i], Integer.toString(stock[i][2]), 40);
            String space3 = placeNumberToRank(NAMES[i], Integer.toString(stock[i][3]), 45);
            System.out.println(space1);
            System.out.println(space2);
            System.out.println(space3);
            }
            
        }
    public static String placeNumberToRank(String originalStr, String numberToPlace, int rank) {
        int numberOfSpaces = 0;
        numberOfSpaces = rank - originalStr.length() - numberToPlace.length();
        return originalStr+" ".repeat(numberOfSpaces)+numberToPlace;
    }
}
```

The result I need to have is: (note that the last digits are aligned)

```
Spa reine 25cl                   56  200   55
Bru plate 50cl                   42  200   60
Bru pét 50cl                     62  200  125
Pepsi                            45  200  150
Spa orange                       25  200  140
Schweppes Tonic                  72  200   86
Schweppes Agr                    40  200   47
Ice Tea                          48  200   80
Ice Tea Pêche                    24  150   75
Jus d'orange Looza               36  200   90
Cécémel                          15  100   55
Red Bull                         25   80   23
```

The result I currently have is:

```
Spa reine 25cl                   56
Spa reine 25cl                       200
Spa reine 25cl                             55
Bru plate 50cl                   42
Bru plate 50cl                       200
Bru plate 50cl                             60
Bru pét 50cl                     62
Bru pét 50cl                         200
Bru pét 50cl                              125
Pepsi                            45
Pepsi                                200
Pepsi                                     150
Spa orange                       25
Spa orange                           200
Spa orange                                140
Schweppes Tonic                  72
Schweppes Tonic                      200
Schweppes Tonic                            86
Schweppes Agr                    40
Schweppes Agr                        200
Schweppes Agr                              47
Ice Tea                          48
Ice Tea                              200
Ice Tea                                    80
Ice Tea Pêche                    24
Ice Tea Pêche                        150
Ice Tea Pêche                              75
Jus d'orange Looza               36
Jus d'orange Looza                   200
Jus d'orange Looza                         90
Cécémel                          15
Cécémel                              100
Cécémel                                    55
Red Bull                         25
Red Bull                              80
Red Bull                                   23
```

The exercice asks to call the method 3 times and it needs to return the originalStr + spaces. Is there a way to kind of "fuse" everything together?

Comment: Have a look at [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html) (closely related to `System.out.printf`)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `printf()` instead of `println()` like this.

`%-30s` edits the string left justified to a width of 30 characters. `%4d` edits an integer 4 characters wide right justified. `%n` is an OS-specific newline character.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NAMES.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%-30s %4d %4d %4d%n",
        NAMES[i], stock[i][1], stock[i][2], stock[i][3]);
}
```

output:

```
Spa reine 25cl                   56  200   55
Bru plate 50cl                   42  200   60
Bru pét 50cl                     62  200  125
Pepsi                            45  200  150
Spa orange                       25  200  140
Schweppes Tonic                  72  200   86
Schweppes Agr                    40  200   47
Ice Tea                          48  200   80
Ice Tea Pêche                    24  150   75
Jus d'orange Looza               36  200   90
Cécémel                          15  100   55
Red Bull                         25   80   23
```